# Basic rewrite of url

Tags: mod-rewrite

I need a rule that rewrites

> http://example.com/page.html?page=2

to

> http://example.com/page.html/page/2

I already tried this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)page=(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/page/$2/
```

but this does not work! :( Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}    page=(\d+) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /$1/page/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

It should works.